# How to specify more than one option in pytest config [pytest_addoption]

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to add more than one option in the command line for pytest? 
I see that I can add the `pytest_addoption` hook to the conftest.py file, but I'm wondering how to go about adding more than one option(s).

Answer (score 19):

You can specify arbitrarily many command-line options using the `pytest_addoption` hook.

Per the [pytest hook documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=addoption#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption):

> Parameters: parser – To add command line options, call parser.addoption(...). To add ini-file values call parser.addini(...).

The `pytest_addoption` hook is passed a `parser` object. You can add as many command-line options as you want by calling `parser.addoption(...)` as many times as you want.

So an example of adding two parameters is as simple as:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--foo', action='store_true', help='Do foo')
    parser.addoption('--bar', action='store_false', help='Do not do bar')
```

And like any other py.test hook this needs to go into a conftest.py file.

Comment: Hi Frank. I have the seem problem and tried adding parser.addoption() but it doesn't seem to work.  suspect that't because I set the arguments wrong. Then I tried to search for the documentation of parser.addoption() but can't find any. If convenient, would you explain a bit about what does "action=" do in this function?

Comment: Here are the docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.config.Parser.addoption 
It says the args behave like the argparse module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 6):

you can add option by this way as shown below :

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    print('conftest method')
    parser.addoption("--hostip", action = "store", default = "127.0.0.1", help ="host ip address")
    parser.addoption("--port", action="store", default="5000", help="port")

@pytest.fixture
def get_param(request):
    config_param = {}
    config_param["host"] = request.config.getoption("--hostip")
    config_param["port"] = request.config.getoption("--port")
    return config_param
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    print('conftest method')
    parser.addoption("--hostip", action = "store",default = "127.0.0.1",help ="host ip address")
    parser.addoption("--port", action="store", default="5000", help="port")

 @pytest.fixture
 def get_param(request):
    config_param = {}
     config_param["host"] = request.config.getoption("--hostip")
    config_param["port"] = request.config.getoption("--port")
    return config_param
```

After this how do we use the get_param function?
I want that to load data elsewhere

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).